# How to calculate and store shipping rate in Magento 2.3.0?

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, shipping-methods, quote, shipping-address

I'm using Magento v 2.3.0.

I am trying to skip Shipping Address section and navigate directly to Payment section if customer has a default address.

I have overridden below class to change the link of checkout url

> Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link

Function overridden

> getCheckoutUrl

Now I also use the checkout session in above overridden class to get the quote and set the shipping address in it.

I use tablerate_bestway as shipping method.

How do I set the shipping method and recalculate the shipping rate and save it in the quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **set the shipping address** in quote use below code to set shipping method programatically

```
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('shippingMethod') //shipping method
        ->setShippingDescription('shipping method description'); //shipping description
$quote->save();
```

Comment: The starting 5 lines of code worked for me, since shipping rate is calculated again on payment page, there was no need to recalculate it, just set the shipping address and shipping method. Modified above code accordingly, Thanks!